# find element by data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I fill a data of a div in runtime and I need to check if the element exists.

I see in SO some tips about how to do it.

I have in DOM, something as

```
<div id="messages">
 <div class="direct-chat-msg right" data-msg-id="true_5521971319071@c.us_AB57E3CC69662AC4059250385929DD72">
        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
          <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right"></span>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to test if the element exists. I have tried the next, but both doesn´t work :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-msg-id="true_5521999957988@c.us_26B99C7B58A653A4FFCFBD1DFF92498D"]').length>0
```

and

```
$("body").find(`[data-msg-id='${"true_5521999957988@c.us_26B99C7B58A653A4FFCFBD1DFF92498D"}']`).length>0
```

Comment: The `data-msg-id` in your test is not the same as in the HTML. If you make them the same the code works, see https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/n9uaebx7/4/

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. It was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have a `true` prefix here: what about using regex (instead of the whole ID)?

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-msg-id="^true"]') ? foo : bar;
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').find('div[data-msg-id="^true"') ? foo : bar;
```

I don’t know if you have to match the exact value, but it should help. Of course, if you have more instances and you want to check the first, you have to change the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
const dataValue = document.getElementsByClassName("direct-chat-msg right");

if (dataValue[0].hasAttribute("data-msg-id")) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false)
}
```